# rhapsody C++ iostream usage

Tags: c++, iostream, rhapsody

I'm using MSVC9 in Rhapsody to build my model into an executable. I try to use `<iostream>` to log different things in a text file as my model is running for post-treatment. According to a tutorial about iostream I found, I have an operation that does this:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open ("example.txt");
myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
myfile.close();
```

When building, I get an error that the fstream type is unknown.

I also tried to have an attribute that is declared with type `<iostream>::fstream` called `myfile`, removing the first line of my operation's code.
Of course, I added both `<iostream>` and `<fstream>` to the standard headers of my executable (still according to the tutorial).

How could I get this to work ?
Thanks everyone !

Comment: well, are you using "using namespace std"?, if not, you should use std::ofstream. BTW, if you copy the exactly error you are getting maybe someone can help you a little more.

Comment: The name is `std::ofstream`. I don't know where you got `<iostream>::ofstream` from, it's not even in that header, but never mind. And please don't get into the bad habit of [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191).

Comment: Both solutions work. Thank you both !